# React Native slow on showing basic UI element.

Tags: javascript, react-native

[image]

I upload the flow here. After I use Cmd+R to refresh the data, the back button required lots of time to load the icon and image. Is there any way to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: Could have some detail about how those icons and images are rendered. Some code on the `Thread` page and such.

Comment: Did you try it on the mobile device as Release? Remember, in the debug mode, many things are slower and not just the GUI. Try release mode or to deploy on an actual device without debugging.